# Can I use a dynamically selected function for useEffect hook in React/Preact?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, preact

I am building a complex sequence of animation hooks. The selection of animation depends on the `props` receieved by the hook. Traditionally, I would have single `useEffect` and then do everything in it by declaring all the used dependencies in the dependency array.

However, that makes the overall effect very unwieldy. I would like to split that effect into multiple smaller functions where each function will have its own dependency list. Can I do this in Preact/React as I am doing the following:

```
import { useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';


function makeEffect1([anchor]) {
  return () => {
    // Animation type 1

    return () => {
      /* Cleanup effect */
    };
  };
}


function makeEffect2([anchor, popper]) {
  return () => {
    // Animation type 2

    return () => {
      /* Cleanup effect */
    };
  };
}


function makeEffect3([anchor, popper, followWidth]) {
  return () => {
    // Animation type 3

    return () => {
      /* Cleanup effect */
    };
  };
}


function useMyEffect(type, opts) {

  const deps = type === 1
    ? [opts.anchor]
    : type === 2
      ? [opts.anchor, opts.popper]
      : [opts.anchor, opts.popper, opts.followWidth];

  const effectToUse = type === 1
    ? makeEffect1(deps)
    : type === 2 ? makeEffect2(deps) : makeEffect3(deps);

  useEffect(effectToUse, deps);
}
```

Can I use a dynamically chosen function as well as its dynamic dependencies list (which could variable-sized list across re-renders) and then use it in an actual call to **useEffect** hook? Is it breaking the laws of hooks?

Comment: I believe the length of the dependency array isn’t supposed to change between renders. 

I think most people would recommend doing the conditional inside of the effect, but then of course you’ll have to use one giant dependency array which perhaps isn’t great.

Comment: I once broke an `useEffect` which was adding and removing a css class on a certain element based on **timeouts** and **interval** and also simultaneously shuffling some text. It resulted in two hooks - `useAnimationState` and `useShuffle` where the state returned by `useAnimationState` was used by `useShuffle` to trigger a shuffle. It worked out pretty well. Here is the link if it interests you - https://github.com/thenewboston-developers/Website/blob/4ad9ea71c1add0732e17050eb3aed56b903480cc/src/hooks/useAnimationState.ts

Comment: @y2bd That's what I am trying to avoid. Animation looks must run to completion. Too many dependencies are problem

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I will look into it. Thanks for sharing...

Comment: Are you talking about this : you are currently checking each type for choose function to call . instead of this, you don't want to check type mannualy to choose function right ?